# Computer boots normally instead of to USB, ignoring BIOS boot order

Tags: boot, usb, multi-boot, bootable-media, grub2

I have both an Ubuntu 18.10 and a Windows 10 bootable USB drive. I used them to install both operating systems on the same laptop for dual boot. In order to select which one I boot to, I'm using the GRUB menu provided by Ubuntu.

This configuration worked great for about eight months until about a month ago when Windows 10 gave me a BSOD. Now Windows won't boot from the GRUB menu.

In order to install a new version of Windows, I tried to boot from my Windows 10 USB by moving it to the top of the BIOS boot order, but instead it loads the GRUB menu as normal.

I also tried removing all other USB devices besides the Windows USB but it still boots to GRUB. How can I get my computer to boot to a Windows 10 install disk?

Comment: What is the drive configuration for your installed OSes? In other words, is your Ubuntu install located on the same disk as your broken Windows install?

Comment: What do you mean that Windows will not load out of the GRUB menu? What happens instead when you select it?

Comment: First things first - and instead of the above - have you installed in BIOS (Legacy) or UEFI mode? If the latter you should try to boot Windows directly in UEFI settings. If it boot fine then revert to Ubuntu (Grub) to boot Ubuntu again and then do `sudo update-grub`. If Legacy there isn't much you can do but either way you should be able to boot from the USB installer (if you succeed in repairing/reinstalling Windows (Legacy) you'll then have to reinstall Grub). **How did you burned the USB?** There's only one tool that works in Ubuntu for that - MKUSB. (...)

Comment: (...) Anything else will result in an unbootable media. Preferably, if you have another Windows, use the official Media Creation tool. Please [edit] and update the question accordingly.

Comment: @timotree Windows not booting after a BSOD is unfortunately quite common and nothing to do with Grub. And what does the location of the installed OSes has to do with anything? Windows likely needs repair or maybe reinstallation and the problem is the OP couldn't boot the Windows Media, that's all. Please focus on that if you want to help.

Comment: @timotree It just goes to a blank screen and goes no further, almost like the Win10 boot drive was corrupted, but I could see it find from Ubuntu.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia You comment gave the idea that I should try a different boot method, and in searching for how to do, I came across some info on my machine (Toshiba Satellite) that showed how to make it boot CMS instead of UEFI and that seemed to work. The bootable drives were created from another WIN10 machine for the WIn10, and using Rufus for the Ubuntu drive. The update says I indicate rest.

Comment: @JohnBennett I see you edited your post to revert my clarifications and to add your solution. Here on Super User you're encouraged to post an answer to your own question if you solve the problem. Please undo your edit and post it as an answer instead.

Comment: @timotree Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally realized that if I booted using CMS, instead of UEFI, it would boot from the USB drive. I did that with the WIN10 USB, but it wouldn't reinstall to any of the existing partitions. I probably didn't need to, but since most of my important files are either NAS or cloud stored, I just deleted all the partitions and reinstalled windows using a single partitian. It appears to be working for just WIN10 right now, so I'm going to stick with that awhile to make sure it's stable and will try to install Ubuntu later.

Comment: After I reset the BIOS on mine, it would not boot from the HD until I enabled CMS (by trial and error).  Its not at all obvious.